# Does @RequestBody annotation works with the class having private constructor. I'm using Springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using @RequestBody annotation in my controller on a class which is from maven dependency library and it has private constructor.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myApi", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
@ApiOperation(value = "My API", response = CustomResponse.class, notes = "API response beautified")
public String apiOperation( @RequestBody @ApiParam(value = "ReqBody",required = true) 
                            MyAPIBody apiReqBody  ) {

            // some code
            // MyAPIBody is imported from maven dependency lib
            // and has the all constructors as private
    }
```

I am getting 415 error.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-02-03T19:26:30.738+0000",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
 }
```

Can someone suggest what I am doing incorrectly, or i require some change in my project structure .

I feel that it(class with private constructor) should not work with *requestbody*, because when I applied the RequestBody param to some other class,  it worked. But, if someone could explain the reason, i could make well thought changes in my project structure. Or correct me if my feeling is incorrect.

Comment: Add code of controller to your question.

Comment: @BorLaze, added code in controller.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you call POST to "/myApi" with wrong content type. Make sure about it.

Comment: That i have checked multiple times, the content type header i am passing correctly via POSTman

Comment: Just an idea - `produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8"` and `"Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported"` - there is no space in client request - can you add and tell about result? Else I have no ideas - all looks ok...